# $R/\langle p \rangle$ is an integral domain, proof verification

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R$ be a ring, and let $p$ be a prime element in $R$.

Then $R/\langle p \rangle$ is an integral domain.

---

So first I like to try to decode a question.

$p$ being prime means $p|ab \implies p|a$ or $p|b$. $R/\langle p \rangle $ being an integral domain, means that if $ab \equiv 0 \pmod p$ then $a \equiv 0 \pmod p$ or $b\equiv 0 \pmod p$.

Then proof(?): Let $a,b\in R$ If $ab\equiv 0 \pmod p$ then $p|ab$ so either $p|a$ or $p|b$ so then $a\equiv 0 \pmod p$ or $b\equiv 0 \pmod p$, and we are done I believe.

---

Is that all there is to it?

Comment: Looks good -see answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/980657/verifying-proof-an-ideal-p-is-prime-ideal-if-r-p-is-an-integral-domain). I assume that $R$ is given to be commutative, because an integral domain has to be a commutative ring. Note that your question is more or less a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's all there is to it (assuming that $R$ is commutative).

Your notation is a bit unusual though; the notation $x\equiv y\pmod{z}$ is used for $x,y,z\in\Bbb{Z}$, or slightly more generally when working in a number ring (like $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ or $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$). In a general commutative ring one would denote the ideal generated by $p$ by $(p)$, and write:

*The ring $R/(p)$ is an integral domain, if $ab\in(p)$ implies that $a\in(p)$ or $b\in(p)$.*

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll try that in future. I supposed it might be abnormal

Comment: The notation $x\equiv y \pmod z$ is actually often used when $z$ is an ideal in for example algebraic number theory.